# Use of popen in pipes in c

Tags: c, pipe, popen

i am taking the command like ls as input and executing the command using popen and storing the result in the buffer. However it is not printing all the contents of the command. Please help me.
PS It was able to work when the whole code was in main. I have tried gdb but i am not able to do the debugging.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>



void process_command(char * command, char * buffer)
{
    int     fd[2], nbytes;
    pid_t   childpid;
    char    readbuffer[1025];
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    pipe(fd);


    if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
    }

    int b = 0;
    int status = 0;

    if(childpid == 0)
    {
            /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
            close(fd[0]);
            fp = popen(command,"r");

            /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
          while((b = fread(readbuffer,1,1024,fp)) > 0)  
               write(fd[1], readbuffer, b);

          status = pclose(fp);

     }

    else
    {
            /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
            close(fd[1]);
            waitpid(childpid,&status,0);
            /* Read in a string from the pipe */
           do
          {
            nbytes = read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
          }while(nbytes == -1);
          buffer[nbytes] = '\0';  
    printf("Received string: %s", buffer);
    }


}


#define MAX 1024

int main(void)
{
  char command[MAX] ;
  char buffer[MAX];
  scanf("%s",command);
  process_command(command,buffer);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: why child and parent? why not write directly to `buffer`?

Comment: there  is  a problem of incomplete write to the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you read the output from the child process. Particularly, this statement:

```
        nbytes = read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

The array `buffer` was passed from `main()` and it gets converted into a pointer in the function `process_command()`. So `sizeof(buffer)` is going to the the size of the pointer, not the array, which is same as `sizeof(char*)`. Let's say you are on a 64-bit system with 8 bytes for pointer size. So you are only going to read only 8 bytes.

Either pass the array size as an additional argument or use `MAX`:

```
        nbytes = read(fd[0], buffer, MAX);
```

Additional notes:

- You are reading the command using `%s` which can't read space separated input. So if you want to run `ls /tmp` then it's not going to work. Consider using `fgets()`.
- Even with the correct buffer size, you are going to read only the 1024 bytes. So if the output from the child process longer then it'll be truncated. Better would be to `read()` as long as there's output and print it *inside* the loop.